# Search multiple contain conditions in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write some SQL to query a bank statement table, I would like to populate a column as 'Exclude' if any of the 5 bank statement description columns contain 'SURPLUS CASH','CHQ IN AT' or 'ELECTR CHARGE'

My current attempt is

```
select statement_no
      ,bank_text_1
      ,bank_text_2
      ,bank_text_3
      ,bank_text_4
      ,bank_text_5
      ,amount
      ,case
           when bank_text_1 like '%SURPLUS CASH%'
                or bank_text_1 like '%CHQ IN AT%'
                or bank_text_1 like '%ELECTR CHARGE%'
                or bank_text_2 like '%SURPLUS CASH%'
                or bank_text_2 like '%CHQ IN AT%'
                or bank_text_2 like '%ELECTR CHARGE%'
                or bank_text_3 like '%SURPLUS CASH%'
                or bank_text_3 like '%CHQ IN AT%'
                or bank_text_3 like '%ELECTR CHARGE%'
                or bank_text_4 like '%SURPLUS CASH%'
                or bank_text_4 like '%CHQ IN AT%'
                or bank_text_4 like '%ELECTR CHARGE%'
                or bank_text_5 like '%SURPLUS CASH%'
                or bank_text_5 like '%CHQ IN AT%'
                or bank_text_5 like '%ELECTR CHARGE%'
               then 'Exclude'
           else ''
       end as checker;
```

It's very mess and doesn't seem very efficient. Does anyone have suggestions for a better way?

Many Thanks

Example outcome data:

```
Statement_no | bank_text_1 | bank_text_2         | bank_text_3    | bank_text_4 | bank_text_5  | amount | checker
0001         | SURPLUS CASH|                     |                |             |              |125.00  |Exclude
0002         | M THOMAS    |TRAINING FEE         |CHQ IN AT 100217|             |              |470.00  |Exclude
0003         |SWALEC       |Training Centre One  |Abergaveny      |             |Electr Charges|700.00  |Exlcude
0004         |M Thomas     |Training Centre Hire |                |             |              |850.00  |
```

Comment: If you are using some kind of data access such as JDBC (Java) or ADO.NET (.NET), you can use parameters. Using parameters makes your query no messy anymore. I prefer the way you have already because it is easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is a CROSS APPLY

```
Select statement_no
     , bank_text_1
     , bank_text_2
     , bank_text_3
     , bank_text_4
     , bank_text_5
     , amount  
     , B.Checker
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select Checker = case when count(*)>0 then 'Exclude' else '' end
               From ( values (A.bank_text_1)
                    ,(A.bank_text_2)
                    ,(A.bank_text_3)
                    ,(A.bank_text_4)
                    ,(A.bank_text_5) ) C1 (Value)
                Where charindex('SURPLUS CASH',Value)
                     +charindex('CHQ IN AT',Value)
                     +charindex('ELECTR CHARGE',Value) 
                     >0
             ) B
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Prefect. Thanks so much, exactly what i needed. Never heard of Cross Apply before...a weekend of writing up and googling ahead. Cheers John.

Comment: @BlueFrog Happy it helped.  CROSS APPLY is a great feature.  Think of it as a sub-routine

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
 , checker = case 
    when charindex('SURPLUS CASH',concat(bank_text_1, bank_text_2, bank_text_3, bank_text_4, bank_text_5))>0
      or charindex('CHQ IN AT',concat(bank_text_1, bank_text_2, bank_text_3, bank_text_4, bank_text_5))>0
      or charindex('ELECTR CHARGE',concat(bank_text_1, bank_text_2, bank_text_3, bank_text_4, bank_text_5))>0
      then 'Exclude' 
    else '' 
    end
from t
```

results: http://rextester.com/VBOC27547

```
+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------+----------------+--------+---------+
| statement_no |  bank_text_1  |      bank_text_2      |   bank_text_3    | bank_text_4 |  bank_text_5   | amount | checker |
+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------+----------------+--------+---------+
|         0001 |  SURPLUS CASH |                       |                  |             |                | 125,00 | Exclude |
|         0002 |  M THOMAS     | TRAINING FEE          | CHQ IN AT 100217 |             |                | 470,00 | Exclude |
|         0003 | SWALEC        | Training Centre One   | Abergaveny       |             | Electr Charges | 700,00 | Exclude |
|         0004 | M Thomas      | Training Centre Hire  |                  |             |                | 850,00 |         |
+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------+----------------+--------+---------+
```

I tested the performance of this compared to John Cappelletti's answer over 1,000,000 rows and I would say they are comparable.

My personal preference would be John's answer, using `cross apply()`.

In the sets below, the first query in each set uses `charindex(...,concat(..)`, the second is John's `cross apply()` version.

The hardware specs on this instance are pretty weak though, so your mileage will vary.

```
-----------------------

(1000000 row(s) affected)
Table 't'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8153, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 3010 ms,  elapsed time = 8750 ms.

(1000000 row(s) affected)
Table 't'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8153, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 5585 ms,  elapsed time = 8725 ms.

-----------------------

(1000000 row(s) affected)
Table 't'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8153, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 3307 ms,  elapsed time = 8685 ms.

(1000000 row(s) affected)
Table 't'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8153, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 5663 ms,  elapsed time = 8913 ms.

-----------------------

(1000000 row(s) affected)
Table 't'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8153, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 3073 ms,  elapsed time = 8414 ms.

(1000000 row(s) affected)
Table 't'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8153, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 5647 ms,  elapsed time = 9049 ms.

-------------------

(1000000 row(s) affected)
Table 't'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8153, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 3011 ms,  elapsed time = 8706 ms.

(1000000 row(s) affected)
Table 't'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8153, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 5491 ms,  elapsed time = 8704 ms.

-----------------------
```

Comment: Way to go the extra mile  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit tidier, it should perform equally though:

```
SELECT statement_no, 
       bank_text_1, bank_text_2, bank_text_3, bank_text_4, bank_text_5,
       amount,
       IIF(x.IsChecked = 1, 'Exclude', '')
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(CASE 
                 WHEN (t.v LIKE '%SURPLUS CASH%') OR 
                      (t.v LIKE '%CHQ IN AT%') OR 
                      (t.v LIKE '%ELECTR CHARGE%') 
                   THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
              END) AS IsChecked
   FROM 
   (      
      VALUES (bank_text_1), (bank_text_2), (bank_text_3), (bank_text_4), (bank_text_5)
   ) AS t(v) 
) AS x
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
select statement_no
      ,bank_text_1
      ,bank_text_2
      ,bank_text_3
      ,bank_text_4
      ,bank_text_5
      ,amount
      ,case
           when q.item is not null
               then 'Exclude'
           else ''
       end as checker
from queries 
left join
(
       select '%CHQ IN AT%' item union
       select '%ELECTR CHARGE%' item union    
       select '%SURPLUS CASH%' item
) q on bank_text_1 like item or 
       bank_text_2 like item or
       bank_text_3 like item or
       bank_text_4 like item or
       bank_text_5 like item
```

I am not sure about the performance but in my opinion join are lighter than cross apply. If you can share the benchmarks I will be interested.